# Spring boot rabbitmq connection retry configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have spring boot cloud microservices with rabbitmq, I'm using docker-compose to start all containers. Rabbitmq need some time to start and before it finishes starting I see a lot of connecting attempts:

```
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.351  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.351  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.370  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.370  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.378  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.379  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.379  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.386  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.386  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.391  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
config-service_1          | 2019-06-22 16:13:13.401  INFO 6 --- [pool-2-thread-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq:5672
```

How I can configure retry timeout for rabbitmq connection?
I have not found any `spring.rabbitmq.**` property to do this.

**Update**

Have found a problem but still can't fix it.
I have a logging configuration that sends logs via rabbitmq appender, here is `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="appName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="rabbitMqHost" source="spring.rabbitmq.host" defaultValue="localhost"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="rabbitMqPort" source="spring.rabbitmq.port" defaultValue="5672"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="rabbitMqUsername" source="spring.rabbitmq.username" defaultValue="guest"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="rabbitMqPassword" source="spring.rabbitmq.password" defaultValue="guest"/>
    <appender name="AMQP" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender">
        <host>${rabbitMqHost}</host>
        <port>${rabbitMqPort}</port>
        <username>${rabbitMqUsername}</username>
        <password>${rabbitMqPassword}</password>
        <applicationId>${appName}</applicationId>
        <contentType>application/log</contentType>
        <exchangeName>gc.log</exchangeName>
        <declareExchange>true</declareExchange>
        <deliveryMode>NON_PERSISTENT</deliveryMode>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <layout>
            <pattern>
                ${appName}
                %date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", UTC}
                %thread
                %level
                %logger{36}
                %message
            </pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="AMQP"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

if I delete this config everything works well.
So, now the question is how can I configure connection factory recovery interval for `AmqpAppender`

Comment: Can you post here your connection factory configuration.

Comment: @BipilRaut I don't have any, I'm using default, the only one config I have is `spring.rabbitmq.host=${RABBITMQ_HOST:localhost}` in the `bootstrap.properties` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently exposed as a Boot property, but you can set the `recoveryInterval` or `recoveryBackOff` on the rabbit listener container factory.

Simply get a reference to the container factory in some configuration class (or override Boot's default auto-configured factory) and set the property.

e.g.

```
@Bean
public Object configure(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory) {
    factory.setRecoveryInterval(10_000L);
    return null; // you can return null as long as you are on Boot 2.x.
}
```

Please open a Boot improvement GitHub issue to expose this as a property.

**EDIT**

Your original question made no mention that you are using RabbitMQ for logging only. **In future, please be more clear in your questions, in order to get a more timely correct answer.**

The above answer applies to `@RabbitListener` methods attempting to connect to the broker.

Since logging is a "publishing" event a connection attempt will be made each time you attempt to send a log (and for the retries) and hence you'll get that INFO log.

The only way to suppress those logs is to change the log level for `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory` to WARN.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didn't work for me, please see an update

Comment: You didn't say you were only using the appender. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I'm using @RabbitListener too